# Ansible and Kerberos

Tags: windows, ansible, kerberos

I have a question how can I make friends Ansible and Kerberos. 
That's what's in the file vars

---

ansible_user                            : ansible@test.LOCAL
ansible_password                        : aqweASD(*
ansible_port                            : 5986
ansible_connection                      : winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation    : ignore
ansible_winrm_transport                 : kerberos

My error

Windows10 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "kerberos: authGSSClientStep() failed: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Server not found in Kerberos database', -1765328377)), ssl: the specified credentials were rejected by the server",
    "unreachable": true
}

Could you please help me?)))
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual content of hosts file, the command line and playbook it's a bit difficult but I would suggest the following solution:
run kinit on the ansible controller and see if it works, if so then I would suggest testing without ssl.

if kinit doesn't work it could be from number of reasons covered [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#kerberos).

usually missing python packages or problems in krb5.conf